# Android: EditText not allow special characters with Next softkey

Tags: android

I have an EditText which is required to accept only alphanumeric characters. No any special ones allowed (such as: Á, Â...)

I added some properties:

```
android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters|textFilter"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "
                android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext"
                    android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/txtYearOfBirth"
                    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/txtYearOfBirth"
                    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/txtFirstName"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtFirstName"
```

It worked fine for no special characters but the soft key Next is replaced by Enter:

[image]

How can I keep the Next button instead?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these following properties of EditText and check

```
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: Yes, it worked for me, thank you very much. So the problem is not cause by android:digits? But why if I remove this property, the Next button is displayed even without maxLines and singleLine?

Comment: The problem is somehow caused by `android:digits`, not really sure why though.